# How to generate a specific url to an email in ms exchange server using message id?

Tags: windows, email, exchange, outlook-web-access

I am writing an email client application for ms-exchange.
I have the full email data (content and headers including message id)  fetched from  exchange server (I used IMAP for fetching the messages).

My client application will list the messages one by one with subject as clickable links.
When clicked on a message, it should take the user to the exchange webaccess with the specific message opened in browser.

My question is, how do I form a link to the specific email using messageid or any other info?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a URL like the following:

`https://myserver/owa/?ae=Item&a=Open&t=IPM.Note&id=[ItemId]`

Check out [**this article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb891801%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) for more information about the OWA URL parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but this url goes to owa. I want the url to go to http webclient something like  http://server/exchange/username/Inbox/?id=messageId

Comment: ok, just realised that /owa and /exchange are different namings used for exchange server 2003 and 2007 . I tried your solution with /exchange in win 2003, but it did not work for me :(